# How to position a button to right most edge of UITableCell with a margin programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to position a button to the right most side of a `UITableCell`, but it is not working properly. I am using the below code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    flagBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.maxX, y: 0, width: 30, height: 20))
    contentView.addSubview(flagBtn)
    // ...
}
```

The `maxX` is not giving the full width.

[image: pos]

Comment: Are you using autolayouts ?

Comment: I tried adding this `NSLayoutConstraint(item: flagBtn, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true` but it is not working.

Comment: @jsloop Try -> `self.frame.size.width - 30`

Comment: It move to the left.

Comment: call it in `draw(rect` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use constraints to achieve this.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    flagBtn = UIButton()
    contentView.addSubview(flagBtn)

    flagBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    flagBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    flagBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    flagBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    flagBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
}
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor) you can read more about `NSLayoutAnchors`

Answer (score 1):

First declare you UIbutton as a lazy property like below

```
lazy var flagBtn: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("foo", for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
```

Secondly add your constraint

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    contentView.addSubview(flagBtn)

    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: flagBtn.topAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
    contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: flagBtn.rightAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
    flagBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    flagBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}
```

Hope it will help you.